# Для чего нужен tools.jar?

Tags: java

Разбирая пример написания класса Pair, столкнулся с тем, что такой класс уже реализован как `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair`. В стандартных библиотеках его не оказалось и пришлось через Project Structure подключать tools.jar, который находится в JDK `/jdk1.8.0_144/lib/tools.jar` и через `import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Pair;` уже далее можно было использовать этот класс.

В связи с этим возникли вопросы, почему эта библиотека не подхватывается как стандартная (использую IDEA 2018.1.2 UE)? Для чего используется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте лучше [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html). В tools.jar содержатся пакеты закрытого API используемого утилитами входящими в состав JDK. В частности компилятор javac использует классы из пакета com.sun.tools.javac для парсинга исходного кода в AST-представление. В 9-й версии tools.jar убран из JDK.